# How to fetch the child nodes of repeated elements in java for nodelist

Tags: java, dom, nodelist

I need to fetch the value of the `name` element which is a child of an `e` element:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>
                <e><name>123</name></e>
                <e><name>456</name></e>
                <e><name>456</name></e>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

This is my code:

```
NodeList lineItemAttributeChildrenList =
    doc.getElementsByTagName("e").item(0).getChildNodes();

if(lineItemAttributeChildrenList != null &&
   lineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Inside if and checking length" +
                       lineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength());

    for (int i = 0; i < lineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println("i " + i);
        System.out.println("inside for");
        System.out.println("name==============" +
                           lineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i).getNodeName());
        System.out.println("value==============" +
                           lineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i).getTextContent());
    }
}
```

From the above code I just get the first inner element name value for the `e` element, but for the remaining 2 I am not able to get those values. It is not going to the second `e` element in the for loop.

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting 0th element of the NodeList of "e" elements.

```
    NodeList LineItemAttributeChildrenList = doc.getElementsByTagName("e").item(0).getChildNodes();
...
 for (int i = 0; i < LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength(); i++) {
```

You should iterate through the NodeList itself instead of the children of the first element. Here is how your new code would look:

```
    NodeList LineItemAttributeChildrenList = doc.getElementsByTagName("e");
    if (LineItemAttributeChildrenList != null && LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength() > 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Inside if and checking length"+LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("i "+i);
            System.out.println("inside for");
            System.out.println("name=============="+LineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i).getNodeName());
            System.out.println("value=============="+LineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
     }
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the element value like 123 only by specifying the element name "name"

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing only first item thats why you are getting 1 result. try below. Check 'z' in eNodes.item(z)

```
    NodeList eNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("e");
    for (int z = 0; z < eNodes.getLength(); z++) {
        NodeList LineItemAttributeChildrenList = eNodes.item(z).getChildNodes();
        if (LineItemAttributeChildrenList != null && LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Inside if and checking length" + LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength());
            for (int i = 0; i < LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println("i " + i);

                System.out.println("inside for");
                System.out.println("name==============" + LineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i).getNodeName());
                System.out.println("value==============" + LineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i).getTextContent());

            }

        }

    }
```

You can directly get name nodes and iterate over it to get values as below

```
NodeList nameNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
for (int i = 0; i < nameNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    String value = nameNodes.item(i).getTextContent();
    System.out.println("value==============" + value);
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the specifically the value of name tag only by specifying the name of the element like "name"

Comment: @Sangeethacg answer is edited to get the values from directly name nodes.

Comment: thanks For your response, this is the other way we can achieve , just thought to share :)                                                                 if(((Node)LineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i).getChildNodes()).getNodeName().equals("name")) then get the value of name

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over wrong Node

Take a look below:

```
NodeList LineItemAttributeChildrenList = doc.getElementsByTagName("e"); // Finding all 'e' s
          if (LineItemAttributeChildrenList != null && LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength() > 0) {
                  System.out.println("Inside if and checking length"+LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength());
                    // Iterate over 'e' s
                    for (int i = 0; i < LineItemAttributeChildrenList.getLength(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("i "+i);
                         Node e = LineItemAttributeChildrenList.item(i); 
                         // Access the 'name' node for this 'e'
                         Node name = e.getChildNodes()[0] // We know that 'e' has only one child.
                             System.out.println("name=============="+name.getNodeName());
                            System.out.println("value=============="+name.getTextContent());


                            }


                    }
```