# getElementsByTagName from org.w3c.dom not fetching all child nodes

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to get `getElementByTagName("NAME").item(0).getTextContent()` to print all the child elements (`"CONNECTION"` and `"DISTANCE"`) of my xml to the console. The `item(0)` call is apparently only printing the first element of the `ArrayList` connections.

**xml:**

```
<ROW>    
 <FACILITY>SEATTLE, WA</FACILITY>
 <CONNECTIONS>
   <CONNECTION>
     <NAME>FARGO, ND</NAME>
     <DISTANCE>1426</DISTANCE>
   </CONNECTION>
   <CONNECTION>
     <NAME>SAN FRANCISCO, CA</NAME>
     <DISTANCE>808</DISTANCE>
   </CONNECTION>
 </CONNECTIONS>
</ROW>
<ROW>
 <FACILITY>SAN FRANCISCO, CA</FACILITY>
 <CONNECTIONS>
   <CONNECTION>
     <NAME>SEATTLE, WA</NAME>
     <DISTANCE>808</DISTANCE>
   </CONNECTION>
   <CONNECTION>
     <NAME>DENVER, CO</NAME>
     <DISTANCE>1249</DISTANCE>
   </CONNECTION>
   <CONNECTION>
     <NAME>LOS ANGELES, CA</NAME>
     <DISTANCE>382</DISTANCE>
   </CONNECTION>
 </CONNECTIONS>
</ROW>
```

**java:**

```
ArrayList<String> connections = new ArrayList<>();
NodeList connectionsList = elem.getElementsByTagName("CONNECTIONS");
for (int j = 0; j < connectionsList.getLength(); j++) {
    if (connectionsList.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        continue;
    }

    entryName = connectionsList.item(j).getNodeName();
    if (!entryName.equals("CONNECTIONS")) {
        System.err.println("Unexpected node found: " + entryName);
        return;
    }

    // Get some named nodes
    elem = (Element) connectionsList.item(j);
    String connectionName = elem.getElementsByTagName("NAME").item(0).getTextContent();
    String connectionDist = elem.getElementsByTagName("DISTANCE").item(0).getTextContent();
    facilities.addConnection(facilityName, connectionName, (Integer.parseInt(connectionDist)));

    // Create a string summary of the tags
    connections.add(connectionName + ":" + connectionDist);
}
```

The output should look something like this:

```
Facility: SEATTLE, WA Direct Links: [FARGO, ND:1426, SAN FRANCISCO, CA:808]

Facility: SAN FRANCISCO, CA Direct Links: [SEATTLE, WA:808, DENVER, CO:1249,  LOS ANGELES, CA:382]
```

The actual output only prints the first city (`"CONNECTION"`) and mileage for each row.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch the child nodes of repeated elements in java for nodelist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867452/how-to-fetch-the-child-nodes-of-repeated-elements-in-java-for-nodelist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your xml structure you need to iterate on CONNECTION nodes and for each of them print NAME and DISTANCE text content.

```
    NodeList connectionsList = doc.getElementsByTagName("CONNECTIONS");
    for (int j = 0; j < connectionsList.getLength(); j++) {
        if (connectionsList.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            continue;
        }

        String entryName = connectionsList.item(j).getNodeName();
        if (!entryName.equals("CONNECTIONS")) {
            System.err.println("Unexpected node found: " + entryName);
            return;
        }

        // Get some named nodes
        Node elem = (Element) connectionsList.item(j).getChildNodes(); // list of CONNECTION ELEMENTS
        List<String> facilities = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i< elem.getChildNodes().getLength() ;i++){
            Node subElem =  elem.getChildNodes().item(i); //CONNECTION ELEMENT
            String connectionName ="";
            String connectionDist = "";
            for(int k = 0 ; k< subElem.getChildNodes().getLength(); k++){
                Node connectionElem = subElem.getChildNodes().item(k);
                if("NAME".equals(connectionElem.getNodeName())){
                    connectionName = connectionElem.getTextContent();
                }
                else if("DISTANCE".equals(connectionElem.getNodeName())){
                    connectionDist = connectionElem.getTextContent();
                }
                if(!connectionDist.equals("") && !connectionName.equals("")) {
                    facilities.add(connectionName + " , " + connectionDist);
                    connectionDist ="";
                    connectionName = "";
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Facility: "+doc.getElementsByTagName("FACILITY").item(j).getTextContent() +"  Direct Links: "+facilities);
    }
```